# Unable to get filesize of resized image when outputting with a height > 999px

Tags: php

To make things easier for 'less tech savvy' people in my workplace I put together a webpage to resize images for them when they are working on the company websites or publisher documents etc.

If the output image size (height in this case) is greater than 999px PHP throws an error: `PHP Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /[...]/squish.php on line 39`

I imagine the actual problem will either be with my `imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);` or how I have calculated the 'new width' of the image: 
`$new_height = $_POST["size"]; $new_width = floor($width * ($new_height / $height));`

On the index page I just had a Select box with some predefined heights for the user to select from, one of them was 1000..This has been in place for months and I have only just realised that option has an issue.

Sample code below:

'index.html'

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Squish - Image resizing.</title>
<script>
    function submitTheSquisher() {
        document.getElementById("squisher").submit()
        hideStuff();
    }
    function hideStuff() {
        document.getElementById("stufftohide").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("resetFormBtn").value = "Squish Again!";
    }
    function resetForm() {
        document.getElementById("squisher").reset();
        document.getElementById("stufftohide").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("resetFormBtn").value = "Reset From";
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='headerWrapper'>
<div class='screenWidth'><img src='logo.png' style='padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;' /></div>
</div>
<div class='screenWidth' style='background:white;'>
<div style='padding:10px;'>
<h2>Image Squisher</h2>
<p>This tool resizes image for use on the Website or on Publisher. It supports .png .jpg and .gif formats. All images are exported as .jpg.</p>
<form action="squish.php" id='squisher' name='squisher' method="post" target='result' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id='stufftohide'>
    Select a size preset:
    <select name='size'>
        <option value='200'>Tiny (Max height 200)</option>
        <option value='400'>Small (Max height 400)</option>
        <option value='600'>Medium (Max height 600)</option>
        <option value='800'>Large (Max height 800)</option>
        <option value='1000'>Extra Large (Max height 1000)</option> <!-- This is the option that causes PHP to throw the error -->
    </select><br/>
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" onchange='submitTheSquisher'><br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Squish it!" name="submitBtn" id="submitBtn" onclick='hideStuff()'>
    </div><br/>
    <input type='button' name='resetFormBtn' id='resetFormBtn' value='Reset Form' onclick='resetForm()' />
</form>
<iframe name='result' id='result' frameborder='0' height='20px'></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

'squish.php'

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submitBtn"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
          // load image and get image size
  switch ($check["mime"]) {
    case "image/jpeg":
        $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        break;
    case "image/gif":
        $img = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        break;
    case "image/png":
        $img = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        break;
}

  $width = imagesx($img);
  $height = imagesy($img);

  // calculate image size
  $new_height = $_POST["size"];
  $new_width = floor($width * ($new_height / $height));

  // create a new temporary image
  $tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

  // copy and resize old image into new image 
  imagecopyresized($tmp_img, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

  // save image into a file

  $theFileName = explode('.', $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

  $quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($theFileName[0]) . $_POST["size"] . '.jpg', '"\\'));
$size   = filesize($tmp_img);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);


  imagejpeg($tmp_img,NULL,100);
  imagedestroy($tmp_img);

    } else {
        echo "File is not an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

I should note, when `$_POST["size"]` is 1000, an image does start to download, I got 1308kb before a 'Network Error' occurred; The log only shows one error as mentioned above.

[image: Failed - Network error]

Comment: `$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor(...); ... filesize($tmp_img);` I mean, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I wanted to get the filesize of the new image I had created so it could be inserted into the header information.

Comment: You don't actually need to do that, but if you insist then you will need to save the image somewhere. One way of doing it would be `ob_start(); imagejpeg(...); $jpeg = ob_get_clean(); $length = strlen($jpeg); header(...); echo $jpeg;`

Comment: If I don't need it then I will remove it :-) I was just trying to be thorough with my header information. I will test it without and see what happens.

Comment: Commented out `$size= filesize($tmp_img);` and `header('Content-Length: ' . $size);` and now it works...so thanks for that! I am not sure what the issue is though? Why only when over 1000px? Seems bizarre.